# unable to fetch message from kafka topic in spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using **KafkaUtils.createDirectStream** to fetch message from kafka topic in spark streaming. I am submitting my spark job using spark2-submit (cloudera distribution 5.10). The issue is that spark streaming job is not able to fetch message from the kafka topic. The log says nothing and there is no error message either.

Only output I see in the log in as below:

INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0.0
   INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : b8642491e78c5a13

I am using kafka-console-producer to publish the message to the topic.
When i use kafka-console-consumer to fetch the message, it is successfully retrieved.

Below is  my configuration:

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
"bootstrap.servers" -> "ud-hadoopn-1:9092",
"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
"key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"group.id" -> "spark-consumer")
```

Please find below the complete spark streaming code:

```
  package com.model

  import org.apache.spark._
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

 import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
 import org.apache.spark.sql._
 import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
 import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator
 import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
 import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
 import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel
 import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator }
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ StreamingContext, Seconds }
 import org.apache.spark.ml.{ Pipeline, PipelineStage, PipelineModel }
 import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics
 import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
 import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
 import java.io.StringWriter
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{ DeserializationFeature, 
 SerializationFeature }
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
 import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord
 import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{ StringSerializer, 
 StringDeserializer }
 import java.util.Properties
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ KafkaUtils, 
 LocationStrategies, 
 ConsumerStrategies }
 import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject

object StreamingApp {

def main(args: Array[String]) {

case class Prediction(
  fabricKey: Long,
  prediction: Long)

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamingApp").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val errorRecords = sc.accumulator(0)
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]") 
.appName("StreamingApp").getOrCreate()

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

import sqlContext._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val inputTopic = "mlIn"
val kafkaParams = Map(
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "ud-hadoopn-1:9092",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "spark-consumer")

val outputTopic = "mlOut"
val kafkaParamsProd = Map(
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "ud-hadoopn-1:9092",
  "key.serializer" -> classOf[StringSerializer],
  "value.serializer" -> classOf[StringSerializer],
  "group.id" -> "spark-consumer")

 val modelC = 
 CrossValidatorModel.load("/user/root/src/main/resources/model")
 val modelBC =ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(modelC)
 val jacksonWrapper = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(JacksonWrapper())
 val kafkaSink = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(KafkaSink(kafkaParamsProd))

 val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
  ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](Set(inputTopic), 
kafkaParams))

val lines = stream.map(consumerRecord => 
consumerRecord.value().asInstanceOf[String])

lines.foreachRDD(jsonRDD =>
  {
              import spark.implicits._
              val dataDF =  spark.read.json(jsonRDD)
              dataDF.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
              if (spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable").count() > 0) {
                  println("************mytable********")
                  spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable").show()
                  val predictions = modelBC.value.transform(dataDF)
                  println("************Prediction********")
                  predictions.select("KEY","prediction").show()
                  val pDF1 = predictions.select("KEY","prediction")
                  val pDF=  pDF1.columns.foldLeft(pDF1) {
                    (newDF, colName) => newDF.withColumn(colName, 
              pDF1(colName).cast("long"))
            }
                   val x = pDF.rdd.map( row => Prediction( 
        row.getLong(0),row.getLong(1) ) )
                   x.foreach { msg =>
                     val json =jacksonWrapper.value.send(msg)
                     println("***json=" + json)
                     kafkaSink.value.send("mlOut", json)
                  }
              }


    })

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
 }
```

Comment: It is better to solve it if you give some code.

Comment: Please find below the complete spark streaming code

Comment: hi  Xinstein, i have added the code in post

Comment: Have you tried to set the value of "auto.offset.reset" to "earliest"?

Comment: The issue was because kafka configuration done via CM was not correct. Once the config issue is fixed, it started working fine.